# RecyclerView - Add row to adapter dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I create a swıpe view layout and add recycler view into it. My code ıs below:

```
swipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(activity);
theme = new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.ScrollBarRecyclerView);
recyclerView = new RecyclerView(theme);

linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
swipeRefreshLayout.addView(recyclerView);
recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I try to add row(listview item) dynamically. The height of the each row may be different. I implement an adapter class by overloading onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder, getCount and getItemViewType methods.

```
public void addItem() {
    // add item to items
    dataAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.length-1);
}
```

It works for 3-4 items. When the scroll is needed to show more rows, the application crashes. Output of the logcat is here:

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{126d708 position=4 id=-1, oldPos=3, pLpos:3 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent}
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5046)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5177)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3330)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3186)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1595)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4560)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
09-25 13:54:23.406 12444 12444 E AndroidRuntime:    at
```

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

How can I add item to scrollable recycler view on dynamıcally?

Comment: are you call addItem method after change collection in adapter? Can you share code of your adapter?

Comment: My adapter class(ecpecially onBindViewHolder) is too long. I couldn't add it.  I have an items list. I create template on onCreateViewHolder, customize the row(text, image) in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Before calling notifyItemInserted, are you also adding the item to adapter dataset?

Comment: I don't use any adapter.add() function.

Answer (score 1):

Append an `item` in your `itemlist` from your activity then simply call `mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();` That's all.